# PHP - Session variable unset while doing header()

Tags: php, session, variables, header

I've been doing a deep research in the web, looking for a solution for this error, but I couldn't fix it yet.
Let me introduce you the situation:

SCRIPT1.php:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['LoadFile'])){
    echo "<span>";
    $MsgId = 91;
    $Msg = GetMsg($language, $MsgId);
    echo $Msg . " ";
    echo "<input name=\"Fleet\" id=\"Fleet\" type=\"file\" />";
    echo "</span>";
}else{
echo "<span>";
    $MsgId = 169;
    $Msg = GetMsg($language, $MsgId);
    echo $Msg . " ";
    $MsgId = 22;
    $Msg = GetMsg($language, $MsgId);
    echo "<a href=\"".$linkpath."inc_load_file.php\">".$Msg."</a>";
echo "</span>";
}
```

The inc_load_file.php contents:

```
<?php
$_SESSION["LoadFile"] = "Load, please";
$_SESSION["ShowLoadingOpt"] = "Show";
//echo $_SESSION["LoadFile"] <---This works correctly, the variable is being properly created.
header("Location: ".$_SESSION["PrevLoc"]);
exit;
?>
```

Note that if I do `print_r($_SESSION)` in the begging of the `Script1`, it shows the following result:

`Array (
    [UID] => 1
    [UName] => Santi 
    [USurname] => MÃ¡rquez 
    [ULvl] => 1 
    [ULang] => en_Gb 
    [Logged] => 1 
    [UEmail] => xxx@xxx.com 
    [User] => smarquez 
    [UCreationDate] => 2015-10-14 
    [UAccessTimes] => 162 
    [UALDesc] => Administrator 
    [CountryCodeKPIReportsGenerator] => 2
)`

My webpage should show a message like:

"File loaded. If you want to load a new file click **here**."

If you click in the link, the `inc_load_file.php` is executed. It creates the `session` `variables` and goes back to the `script1.php`. After doing it, the webpage should show a file input, but actually, it's still showing the link. The `session` variable is not set.

Can you please help me to check why the `session` variables created in inc_load_file.php are not being properly returned after executing the `header()` `function`?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: looks like you forgot `session_start()`. no session_start, any changes to $_SESSION are simply lost.

Comment: Please, have a look in my answer, and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `session_start()` at the beginning of your script, before you try to access `$_SESSION` and before you output anything to the browser.
2. Where is `$_SESSION["PrevLoc"]` set? You use it in the Location header, but we don't see you set its value.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers :)
I'm currently using wamp and the session is starting automatically.
It's correctly started, that's why I'm able to save all this data in the $_SESSION array:

```
[UID] => 1
[UName] => Santi 
[USurname] => MÃ¡rquez 
[ULvl] => 1 
[ULang] => en_Gb 
[Logged] => 1 
[UEmail] => xxx@xxx.com 
[User] => smarquez 
[UCreationDate] => 2015-10-14 
[UAccessTimes] => 162 
[UALDesc] => Administrator 
[CountryCodeKPIReportsGenerator] => 2
```

So, the problem is not the session creation. It's properly created, but $_SESSION["LoadFile"] and $_SESSION["ShowLoadingOpt"] are being unset after the Header().

By the other hand, $_SESSION["PrevLoc"] contents the previous page where the user has been. I deleted some variables from the print_r result due a security reason. Anyways, I tried using $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] too but it didn't work neither.

Thank you very much again for all your support :)